# Bootstrap icon not visible

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In the documentation of bootstrap I read about icons and tried to incorporate them in my file like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title> Getting started with bootstrap</title>
<link href ="css/bootstrap.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class ="container-fluid">
    <header class= "row-fluid">
        <h1 class="span12" >This is my first Bootstrap page.</h1>
    </header>
   <i class="icon-calendar"></i>

</div>
<script src = "js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens. There is no calendar image visible.

Comment: what version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Tag is correct. This happening from somewhere in code.

Comment: Make sure you are loading the glyph file as well

Comment: check your libraries and even your glpyhicons. Are you using the latest version of Twitter bootstrap?

Comment: My bootstrap version is latest(i.e Bootstrap 3). I downloaded it two days ago.

Comment: @Ali what are glyph files ?? where do I search them??

Comment: Okay I just saw you are using BS 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here's the answer. Since you are using Bootstrap 3, you forgot to include the icon package. Here's how you should do it:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>.
```

1. Go here: http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/
2. Click Download from Github
3. Unzip the folder and copy the CSS folder contents to your own CSS folder.
4. Copy the fonts folder as to as in the **same directory** as your css folder.
5. Then once you have added the fonts and the css, add the code as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<i class="icon icon-calendar"> </i>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 3 no longer includes glyphicons in it's base package.  From [Bootstrap 3 RC2 Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#glyphicons),

> With the launch of Bootstrap 3, icons have been moved to a separate repository. This keeps the primary project as lean as possible, makes it easier for folks to swap icon libraries, and makes Glyphicons icon fonts more readily available to more people outside Bootstrap.

Comment: I read the reference you gave. It appears that I was reading older documentations